# Wrong height in Google mobile dev tools

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, google-chrome-devtools

I have a height problem with web mobile dev tools.

```
`function Component() {
  console.log(screen.height);
  return (
    <div className="accueil" style={{ height: screen.height }}>
      {}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

I try to assign a height with react on my "accueil" div.

As you can see, I have the good height but it doesn't fit in mobile mode...

Someone know what happen please ?